# how to calculate interference weight between 20MHz, 40MHz and 11ac 80MHz APs?

Tags: wifi

I want to know how to calculate interference weight in the combination of APs running on different channel frequencies.

Lets say, i have 10 APs, with different modes running, like 11a, 11na and 11ac.

If 11a is running a 20MHz channel say (36), and 11na devices running with 40MHz (36 and 40), and 11ac devices running with 80MHz(36, 40,44,48).

Now how does these frequencies interfere with each other and how to calculate the interference weight among these frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should read the 802.11-2012 standard and 802.11ac amendment to understand the difference in PHY between the 3 modes. But more generally I think a more precise definition of "interference weight" or at least how you would use this measure, is needed to assist.

In practice, interference depends on many variables, is highly dynamic, and has many elements of randomness. The standard allows you to define a quantity measure called RSSI of the signal you are measuring but the actual method is proprietary and no vendor will be the same. Moreover different hardware/firmwave/drivers will measure signal and SNR differently at the exact same location and time.

IMO, all measures of signal quality are by definition averages of some kind. Interference can be more precisely defined and measured on a per-symbol basis but with millions of symbols per second this is of limited use